# Wizard control inner table cellpadding need to reduce

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, wizard

I used wizard control.This code is from pagesource. I want to reduce cellpadding and cellspacing

**cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"** . Where I have to change these values. This is the default wizard control inner table styling. Is it possible to change then how?

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="WizardGL" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
 <tbody>

 <tr style="height:100%;">
    <td>
      ..................................................
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right">
       <table **cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"** border="0">
         <tbody><tr>
            <td align="right">
               <input type="submit"     name="$WizardGL$StepNavigationTemplateContainerID$StepPreviousButton" value=" Previous" >
            </td>
            <td align="right">
              <input type="submit" name="WizardGL$StepNavigationTemplateContainerID$StepNextButton" value="Next " id="WizardGL_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepNextButton" >
            </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change them in the markup for Wizard in your aspx page as shown below.

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0" 
        OnActiveStepChanged="GetFavoriteNumberOnActiveStepIndex"
        BackColor="#FFFBD6" BorderColor="#FFDFAD" BorderWidth="1px" 
         CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="3" Font-Names="Verdana"
        Font-Size="0.8em" Width="322px">
</asp:Wizard>
```

But if you are using layout template with table element in Wizard then you need to make sure that you set cellpadding and cellspacing in markup for layout template also.

Just set these values to what suits your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This one i already tried but it's not affecting in inner table. I dont know where this cellpadding=5 is setting .

Comment: Can you post the complete markup of Wizard control in your aspx page?